# plotnine/ggplot (Python) - stacked bars + width manipulation

Tags: python, pandas, ggplot2, plotnine

I have this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Segment': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'D'},
 '%Value_S=0': {0: 0.489, 1: 0.429, 2: 0.467, 3: 0.461},
 '%Value_S=1': {0: 0.511, 1: 0.571, 2: 0.533, 3: 0.539},
 '%Total': {0: 0.148, 1: 0.076, 2: 0.3, 3: 0.477}})
df
    Segment  %Value_S=0  %Value_S=1  %Total
0   A        0.489       0.511       0.148
1   B        0.429       0.571       0.076
2   C        0.467       0.533       0.300
3   D        0.461       0.539       0.477
```

And I'm trying to do a stacked bar like this one:

[image]

But I need the width of the bars to be from `%Total`. So, to plot the graph above I used this:

```
z = df.melt(id_vars="Segment", value_vars=["%Value_S=0", "%Value_S=1"])
(ggplot(z, aes(x="Segment", y="value")) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill="variable"), stat="identity", position="fill"))
```

and if I add the `width` argument:

```
geom_bar(aes(fill="variable", width= df["%Total"]), stat="identity", position="fill"))
```

It gives me this error:

```
PlotnineError: 'Aesthetics must either be length one, or the same length as the data'
```

I tried the other way also: plotting the width first and then I can't figure out a way to plot the other two variables. The hardest part is this: **the four bars have to cover ALL the graph** (no spaces between them). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You passed the data from melted data frame (`z`), but tried to adjust the bar width by a column of the original data frame (`df`). You need to include the column `%Total` in the melted df:

```
z = df.melt(
    id_vars=["Segment", "%Total"],
    value_vars=["%Value_S=0", "%Value_S=1"]
)
```

And then simply map to the width to `%Total` column:

```
from plotnine import geom_bar, ggplot, aes
(
    ggplot(z, aes(x="Segment", y="value"))
    + geom_bar(
        aes(fill="variable", width="%Total"),
        stat="identity", position="fill"
    )
)
```

which produces:

[image]